# Spring Cloud gateway on kubernetes timeout

Tags: spring, kubernetes, spring-cloud-gateway

My first question on stackoverflow,  hope to get some help

I have a spring cloud gateway (using webflux) on kubernetes. My all other microservices is also sit on kubernetes on same cluster with ingress allowed only from api gateway so that all request can only go through gateway.

Problem I am facing is when I give any other service kubernetes path e.g http://myappservice.namespace.svc.clustor.local as route uri in gateway property and try to hit it gives upstream timeout, but if with in gateway I write a rest controller and call the same service with same kubernetes uri path through a simple rest template it works fine. So for sure it had access and there is no ingress and egress issue but why it could not call other services as proxy is mystery

Anyone have any clue?

Thanks
Ravi

Comment: Can you please try to access the same address from within the Pod's container and share the results? Thanks. Because it can be a DNS or Proxy error. Or simply spring may be causing some trouble.

Comment: Thanks Catastrophe, yes I tried it. Got into the gateway pod and ran curl to other servie with same local url and able to get result. Not sure if x-forwared header is causing issue.. scratching my head

Comment: Than, i believe that it is caused by your application. Since after the container itself, it is the next. Hope you can scratch enough :)

Comment: :-) I am sure it is spring.  The thing is I am not using any custom code it is just spring could gateway proxy pass to kubernetes local url which is not working.. not sure why it matter to ingress whether it is through proxy or originated from the gateway pod.. might get clue checking what ingress check

Comment: Can you answer the question and close the issue then please ? Thanks and good luck